# With Quartz.Net, Is it possible to list all jobs that will be fired on a specific date?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm new to Quartz. I've no idea is there any solution that can get all jobs that will be fired on a specific date?

Say, I created serveral jobs as below:

- Job "A" with cron trigger: "0 0 12 1/1 * ? *", which should be fired every day at 12:00.
- Job "B" with cron trigger: "0 0 12 ? * MON *", which should be fired every Monday at 12:00.
- Job "C" with cron trigger: "0 0 0/1 1/1 * ? *", which should be fired every hour.

Now, is there any solution that can help me get all jobs that will be fire on specific date?

For example:

- On next **Monday**, Job "A", "B" and "C" will be returned. And there should be multiple "C" as it will be fired every hour.
- On next **Friday**, Job "A" and "C" will be returned. And there should be multiple "C" as it will be fired every hour.

Answer (score 0):

If you get an instance of trigger that is used for the job, you can use the following methods defined in [`ITrigger` interface](https://quartznet.sourceforge.io/apidoc/2.0/html/html/869a601f-62a4-8cbd-b1b4-d28e5d054dae.htm):

```
// Returns the next time at which the Quartz.ITrigger will fire, after the given
// time. If the trigger will not fire after the given time, null will be returned.
DateTimeOffset? GetFireTimeAfter(DateTimeOffset? afterTime);


// Summary:
// Returns the next time at which the Quartz.ITrigger is scheduled to fire. If the
// trigger will not fire again, null will be returned. Note that the time returned
// can possibly be in the past, if the time that was computed for the trigger to
// next fire has already arrived, but the scheduler has not yet been able to fire
// the trigger (which would likely be due to lack of resources e.g. threads).
//
// Remarks:
// The value returned is not guaranteed to be valid until after the Quartz.ITrigger
// has been added to the scheduler.
DateTimeOffset? GetNextFireTimeUtc();
```

To get trigger(s) using job name:

```
JobKey jobKey = new JobKey("<job name>");
var triggers = await scheduler.GetTriggersOfJob(jobKey);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try these methods, but why there's no built in solution to solve such questions? I think it's a very common requirement, isn't it? e.g. outlook calender can list all appointments for a day, a week, a month ...